# Lightswitch 2013 Add Relationship.

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm just getting started with Lightswitch (using VS2013). i'm using VisualStudio LightSwitch 2012 book (no 2013's available) and following example. i have a table called enginners whose PK is ID. I have an issues table with an AssignedTo ID. When I got to add a relationship, I can select the tables the multiplicity, but not the fields that form the relationship. all I have is "Navigation Property". If I type "ID" in I get "ID has already been used by another generated member" How the heck do I define which fields are related?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate through the navigation property, it's implicitly using the ID field under the covers.  Keep in mind that LightSwitch is building an OBJECT model over your data, so you can't assume that the keys are as explicitly defined as they would be in an entity-relational database.

This is all an abstraction generated by the Entity Framework to mask complexity from developers.  A developer doesn't generally care what the specifics of the foreign key are - just that there is one, and that it's primary purpose is to uniquely identify a given entity.

Think of it a different way - let's say you have a cat.  Your cat has four legs, two eyes, two ears, etc.  These can have a "business" label - say "right foreleg", "left eye", "right ear". etc.  However, when describing these associated entities to someone who wants to draw the cat, they don't need to know exactly how the legs, eyes and ears are connected to the cat's body and head respectively.  All they need is a way to visualize the respective body part and determine whether it's visible from their perspective. LightSwitch is targeted at people who want to "sketch" business data processing systems... they don't need to know the plumbing - they just need to trust that it works.

Answer (score 0):

When you define relationships between entities of the ApplicationData Datasource (intrinsic database) you don't have to deal with the details of the field defining this associations, Lightswitch takes care about this. But if you define associations between entities of different data sources then you MUST enter the fields that define your relationship.